# Generic detail view PostDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I used get_absolute_url in my model but when I am browsed my post link I got this type error 
AttributeError at /blog/details/Hello-World1/
Generic detail view PostDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.

I would like to create link this link `/Hello-World1/` (mix with title and pk id)

Models.py

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        title = self.title.replace(" ", "-")
        return  reverse('blog:post_details', args=[title+str(self.id)])
```

views.py

```py
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blogs/blog_details.html'
```

urls.py

```py
path('details/<str:new_str>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name="post_details"),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your url should have `pk` arg instead of `new_str`

```
path('details/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name="post_details"),
```

Comment: I got this error now NoReverseMatch at /blog/

Reverse for 'post_details' with arguments '('hello-world1',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/details/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']

Comment: Chnage this `reverse('blog:post_details', args=[title+str(self.id)])` to `reverse('blog:post_details', args=(self.pk,))`

Comment: Actually, i would like to create link this like /hello-world2/ (mixing with title with pk id)

Comment: What you need is a slug field please define a slug field in your django model and use it in url like this `<slug:slug>`. For more info about slug field, please read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#slugfield)

Answer (score 1):

You need to rewrite get_object

view.py

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blogs/blog_details.html'
    
    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        if queryset is None:
            queryset = self.get_queryset()
        new_str = self.kwargs.get('new_str') or self.request.GET.get('new_str') or None

        queryset = queryset.filter(pk=new_str)
        obj = queryset.get()
        return obj
```

see http://www.chenxm.cc/article/1143.html

Answer (score -1):

view.py

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blogs/blog_details.html'
    
    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        if queryset is None:
            queryset = self.get_queryset()
        new_str = self.kwargs.get('new_str') or self.request.GET.get('new_str') or None

        queryset = queryset.filter(pk=new_str)
        obj = queryset.get()
        return obj

see http://www.chenxm.cc/article/1143.html
```